# How to find a good marketing person?

Tags: marketing, selling

I've taken many photos, gotten some favorable comments, and occasionally sell trade or give a few when it serves someone's need.  The emphasis is on the word "few". Photography has been a serious hobby - I'd like to see if I can take it further, to do more business, more selling and knowing better what demand there is for what kinds of images, subject matter, and styles.

Unfortunately, I suck at marketing and sales.  Really, I'd have trouble selling a chunk of warm beef with gravy to a hungry dog.   How might I find someone who can help me make business happen, to help define my market and find customers?

Comment: Do you know what sort of photo sales channel you want to use?  Stock?  Fine art sales?  Event photography?  Weddings?  Corporate?  Etc.... or are you looking for someone who can help you figure that out too?

Comment: Are you looking for information on how to go about finding and employing someone? Or a contract relationship of some sort? How to 'get a manager?' How to find someone who will do marketing and sales 'for free?' Something else?

Comment: This might get better answers asked on the sister site, http://answers.onstartups.com/

Comment: @ahockley: I have only questions, not answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How good is the photography scene or contacts you have at the moment? I'm only really able to provide anecdotal evidence as selling art and creative products is difficult everywhere.

If you have a thriving photography community, I suggest talking to them and going via word of mouth. Volunteer for free photography exhibitions, ask to be someone's assistant, find out if there's a good studio around where you live that needs a part time shooter or will let you rent the studio for a fee. If your stuff is good and you talk to people you should see an uptick in sales if you work at it long enough.

Submit your work for competitions and use that as a way of bolstering your reputation. Additionally the internet is a great platform for showing your work, flikr is good to start with.

Remember an agent is only going to be interested in your work for particular things. If you specialise in fashion photography that's going to be much easier than photojournalism, and weddings tend to be more regular than either of those. You're only limited by what you shoot so the decisions on where you take things will ultimately be up to you. Be aware that many professional photographers find their personal work hard to sell as well.

Happy selling.

Comment: For now, I'm in a small town with little action of any kind.  At least we have a good coffee shop.  Nearest bigger town is an hour drive away.

Answer (score -1):

A UI/UX friend of mine once recommended the following site to me: http://freelanceswitch.com/. I never used it though. But I think that freelancer web portals are one way to go.

Have a nice day
Thomas

Comment: While I'm not responsible for the down-vote I can guess at the reasons for it. First, you should not recommend a service you have not used. Second, you recommend freelance web portals but give no facts or justification to backup your recommendation.